# jQuery fancybox - target specific div #id in iframe and the next one with same #id

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

thinking and trying for hours now but cant get i working

i have:

2 selectors on let say page 1 , on click an i frame open and a div from another page is visible

```
<div>
<a class="more float_r" href="news.html"id=one>Lees Meer</a>
<a class="more float_r" href="news.html"id=two>Lees Meer</a>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery so far

```
$(#one, #two").each(function(i, el) { $(el).fancybox({ 
        'autoDimensions': true, 
        'type': 'iframe', 
        'iframe': { dataFilter: function(data) { return $(data).find('.news:eq(' + i + ')')[0]; } } });});
```

Using this result at all times that a iframe opens but always on the first div , i use to use this with a ajax call but now i want to use it in a iframe

what am i missing here ?

i forgot to tell that i use a pagination plugin on the news.html page on the class .news

Comment: Given the above code, what do you want to do when happens what? Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Ok sorry ,when i click on a with id one  i want to open the first div with the class news from page news.html in a iframe , when i click on a with id two  i want to open the second div with the class news from page news.html in a iframe

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'content' parameter of fancybox:

```
...
'content':function(){
             ///here get content of your news.html in ajax call
             ///filter the response html code to extract your needed div
             ///return the div as html
          },
 'type':'ajax',
 ....
```

I have not tested it and I am not sure how pagination plugin would work wth that, but you may try it.

Comment: thnx for thinking along kwicher , but this didnt work with the pagination :(

Comment: Isn't there a design conflict between pagination plugin and what you want to do with fancybox?